# Python shell execution programatically

Tags: python, subprocess, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop

I have a requirement to run python commands at run on shell programmatically, its almost replicating REPL but programmatically, I tried below code which worked for the first line but it's not carrying the session the way CLI does, kindly help

[image]

```
import subprocess as s
import sys
res=s.run([sys.executable, "-c", "a=5"])
s.run([sys.executable, "-c", "print(a)"])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I am getting the error as those 2 commands are being executed in 2 different processes, is there any way to run in one process but in different lines(Similar to what we do in python interpreter(REPL)), I am working on the requirement to capture python commands from some external files and run them on the shell, so I won't know what command I will be executed until it actually appears in an external file.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: What do you think the error message is trying to tell you?

Comment: Variables aren't going to persist across two separate executions of the Python interpreter. That `a=5` from the first execution isn't relevant to the second, which is why you're getting that `NameError`. I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do so I don't have any particular suggestions for you.

Comment: @larsks thanks for the reply, is there any way to run in one execution but in different lines(Similar to what we do in python interpreter(REPL)), I am working on the requirement to capture python commands from some external files and run them on the shell, so I won't know what command I will be executing until its actually appeared in an external file.

Comment: My best advice for you right now is to update the question to demonstrate clearly what you're trying to accomplish. People aren't necessarily going to see your comment, and even with that comment I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Popen` of `subprocess`. `stdin` is waiting your commands.

```py
import subprocess as s
import sys
res=s.Popen(sys.executable, stdin=s.PIPE)
res.stdin.write(b"a=5\n")
res.stdin.write(b"print(a)")
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but it's not printing any value. Kindly help

Comment: @NewDev I have tested it is printing to output. How do you run the file?

Comment: i ran it from pyCharm, i have attached screenshot to question, kindly take a look at it

Comment: Please run it on the command line. `python test_Selenium.py`

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the help